# Codeigniter, create directory

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new on Codeigniter.
I have a problem & looking for some help.
I want to create directory when I input the data to a database with a directory name, which comes from the array when create a database. If I make a directory with specific name it works.

```html
public function insert()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dname', 'Name', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ddate', 'Date', 'required|date_valid');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->loading_content('admin/new_event');
        } else {
            $panggil = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('dname'),
            'event_date' => $this->input->post('ddate')
            );
            $path ="./lainnya/img/event/".$data->name."/";
            mkdir($path, 0777); --> THIS CODE NOT WORKING
            // mkdir("lainnya/img/event/okdeh",0777); --> THIS CODE IS WORKING
            $this->m_event->form_insert($panggil);
            $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
            $this->loading_content('admin/event', $panggil);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you creating a nested directory?

Answer (score 0):

i already found the answer... Maybe someone out there need it..

```html
public function insert()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dname', 'Name', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ddate', 'Date', 'required|date_valid');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->loading_content('admin/new_event');
        } else {
            $panggil = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('dname'),
            'event_date' => $this->input->post('ddate')
            );
            //$path ="./lainnya/img/event/".$panggil->'name'."/"; ---> **BEFORE**
            $path ="./lainnya/img/event/".$panggil->['name']."/"; -- **NOW**
            mkdir($path, 0777);
            $this->m_event->form_insert($panggil);
            $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
            $this->loading_content('admin/event', $panggil);
        }
    }
```